# JUnit "main (String[]) in extraction cannot be applied to ()"

Tags: java, junit

Ok so I'm trying to test a database extraction model which extracts data from an API and put it into a database. While I know I can't JUnit test a lot of it as it doesn't have any value I'm trying to create JUnit tests to check if the various methods are not null.

I've got this so far

```
    @Test
    public void testMain() throws Exception {

    assertNotNull(extract.main());
    }
```

However the () gets: main (String[]) in extraction cannot be applied to ()
which causes errors and I can't run it.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Inserter inserter = new Inserter();
    Downloader downloader = new Downloader();

    // config for testing
    String currentlyTestingType = "SourceType";
    String currentlyTestingId = "SourceID";


    DataSource dataSource = getDataSource("SOURCEConfig.json");
    String response = downloader.getDataFromApi(currentlyTestingId,currentlyTestingType, dataSource);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    inserter.insertOne(jsonObject, currentlyTestingType , dataSource);
}
```

or am I totally barking up the wrong tree and this entire section can't be JUnit tested?

Comment: What is extract and what is method main?

Comment: @AniketThakur oh sorry, "main" is the main method I'm trying to test and extractor is the file that I'm testing

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. First main method takes a String[] argument, so you cannot just call main(). Secondly main() method does not return anything (void) so you cannot assert it to be not null.

Comment: Isn't unit testing about testing units of code and not the method that is essentially the entire program? I'd consider rethinking your unit test strategy here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have a couple issues off the bat.

First, main takes a String array, but you aren't passing any parameters. Since you aren't using the program arguments, you can pass null -- `main(null)`.

Second, `assertNotNull(Object)` takes an Object. Main doesn't have a return type so you'll get another compilation error on `assertNotNull(void)`

Note: It's not very common to call the main method of any class from another class.

---

As for how to unit test this main method, you might want to use a better testing framework (EasyMock, PowerMock, Mockito, . . .)

Comment: yeah thats what I've been expecting but you can't really mock up the final version as its calling to an API with radically changing formats. However in general I'm supposed to stick to unit testing and have no idea  were to go from here